# Responsive search form in Bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a simple horizontal search & filtering form using Twitter Bootstrap as can be seen in the image attached.
I am trying to build it so it adapts to different screen sizes as shown in the image. The results that I receive from my code aren't according my expectations.

```
<div id="search_block" class="panel-body">
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 control-label" for="v_search">Search:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Search Keywords" value="" name="v_search" id="v_search" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="button-group col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" value="search" name="search" type="submit">Search</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" value="reset" name="reset" type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 control-label" for="filters">Filters:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-2" id="filters">
            <select class="form-control" name="section_id">
                <option value="all">All Sections</option>
                <option value="all">Test</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
                <option value="all">All Categories</option>
                <option value="71">Test</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My code can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/NB89d/

[image: Form layout adaptation to different screen sizes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `col-*-offset` classes to achieve what you want.

### Demo: http://www.bootply.com/126439

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! That seems to almost do the job.
However, I have 2 questions:
1. When resizing the screen, there's a moment where the Reset Button falls below the Search Button, instead of the two buttons falling under the Search input field. Is there some way to indicate to Bootstrap that it should treat those 2 buttons as one element?
2. When one element falls below other element, they are "sticked" together. However, they need to have some spacing between them at least. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Change the button container to `col-md-3` so it has enough room and doesn't wrap. For the margin I think you need to customize the form inputs with CSS: `.form-group input,button,select{margin-bottom:3px;}` I updated the Bootply: http://bootply.com/126439